# Fingerprint reader - ID 147e:2020 Upek - Thinkpad T430

Tags: linux, fingerprint

I'm having some problems with fingerprint reader on Thinkpad T430 ID 147e:2020 Upek

For few days i was trying every tip i could find but it didn't work for me.

Mainly i tried to Build and make it running through Fingerprint GUI and i was able to build it and install it properly (after few fixes) but it simply was not able to pick up my device.

At one point i thought that i have solution, since i realized that Fingerprint sensor on this laptop is quite new and is maybe not supported by default with proprietary libbsapi.so so i tried to follow tips from this blog: http://volker.de/2012/12/fingerprint-gui-und-das-thinkpad-t430s/
Guy has exactly same device and in same PC but as i expected it didn't work for me.

Platform is Debian-squeeze

If you have any idea what could be solution, pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used the same info as you did, but a quick look at the French Ubuntu doc did the fix for me: the problem appears to be that the fingerprint-gui doesn't have access to the USB device bus, thus, we have to give it to it.

Find your device's bus and device adress using the `lsusb` command, for me, it was:

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2020 Upek`

Thus the bus is **001** and the device is **003**. **Let's call them x and y.**
Then, we use `chmod` (apparently it doesn't pose any security threat as the system fixes it by itself):

`sudo chmod 666 /dev/bus/usb/00x/00y`

For me, for instance, it was:
    `sudo chmod 666 /dev/bus/usb/001/003`

Then, follow the instructions given to you by the German guy (volker - the link you cited).
On my side, I was running Ubuntu 12.04 (debian bro'), so I could use the fingerprint PPA. I don't know if Ubuntu PPA's work on debian. I suggest you keep your own install of the fingerprint-gui program, as well as the fix provided by volker's blog post. Then, just launch fingerprint-gui and it should recognize you device.

Comment: OMG i was thinking about that, i even tried to do it but i don't know why it didn't work then.

Anyway, thank you, you got your +150

Comment: Actually there's a small issue: the "chmod fix" gets unfixed when I reboot, since the system resets the permission code to something that doesn't enable fingerprint to access it... so the "swipe your finger" prompt appears without actually activating the hardware... any idea on how to fiw this?

Comment: Check what is the device group in /dev/bus/usb/... I believe that it's in group plugdev so your user should be in plugdev group in order to access it. At least, try to chown the device into that group and add user in it too.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the device's group... but fingerprint-gui isn't a user... Or is it? Which user will I add to this group? 

PS: actually it's a bit more complicated than that, and I can't seem to figure out what's happening: it sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. In all cases, it's not very practical: it sometimes takes several swipes for the system to recognize my fingerprint.

Comment: plugdev is the group in which your device belongs to. So in order to access the device, your user who starts the fingerprint-gui needs to be root or to belong to that group too.

Answer (score 1):

The German blog got actually updated was a problem with the quotes:

For non german users:
Be aware to use the copy and paste funktion to insert the above lines in your 40-libbsapi.rules, because the quotes are different from that quotes that you get when hitting on your keyboard.
It was pain in the a….. to find it out.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to apply [this patch](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/patch/?id=3b3679c900f6739f7067f8d720e15d548bb39be9) to libfprint.